# using watch with ssh

Tags: ssh, xterm, watch

I have a script:

```
export TERM=xterm
watch -t -d -n 1 'netstat -veeantpo | grep 43597
```

when we run this script though ssh, it does not determine the monitor resolution. so lines are wrapped although there is space to show results. You can see the result in the picture.(I have removed the trailing space after `ESTABLISHED`).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `-t` to your ssh. By default when you pass a command to ssh, it doesn't allocate a TTY on the remote host, so the application only has a basic STDOUT pipe to work with.

```
ssh -t foobar 'watch -t -d -n 1 "netstat -veeantpo | grep 43597"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal info is not being passed on to the remote side. You can either tweak your SSH client and server config to pass the variables, or take the easy way and put them inside your command string:

```
"TERM=$TERM COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES watch -n 1 top -bn 1
```

Comment: because we ssh a lot to the server, I would prefer the first options. How we can configure ssh client and server to pass the variables? I am using openssh on debian 6

Comment: Never mind my answer. The forced pseudo-tty allocation is much easier.